# Touchpad heating up on dell inspiron n5010

Tags: 12.04, dell, touchpad, overheating, temperature

My laptop Dell Inspiron N5010 runs an Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 64 bit version. I have installed all the necessary fglrx drivers and the laptop temperature is not very high. It persistently remains between 45-60 degree centigrades. But the problem is that the touchpad is heating up due to some unknown reason and hurting my fingers . In Windows 7, the touchpad did not heat up so much with the laptop temperature staying almost in the same range as in Ubuntu. (I used psensor in Ubuntu and SpeedFan in Windows 7 to determine core temperatures). Can anyone please help me with this, is there any workaround to prevent the touchpad from overheating? Also, will an overheated touchpad cause problems in the laptop in the long run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that Ubuntu get your touchpad hotter in any way.For some reason i have heard a lot that some Dell models have an issue with overheating touch pads after a while.

Probably the touchpad in your Dell is over some hardware that produces a lot of heat (like wireless card,cpu,hard disk) or you laptop is faulty.I don't think Ubuntu have to do any with this.
60 degrees Celcius is too hot to touch,so even though that for a pc/laptop 60 degrees are safe,for your hand ain't.

I will suggest to communicate with Dell or a technician.
Before you do that you can try to see if the fan and the heat-sink are gunked up with dust and that is causing the overheating in the touchpad.

Comment: Well, thank you for your reply. I think you may be right. But, as far as the cooling system in my laptop is concerned, I recently(just a month back) got my entire cooling system changed and replaced by a much more efficient one as a part of general laptop maintenance. Also, I do not think that there is a lot of dust in my laptop as I maintain it pretty well.